# updating the 2nd version of the app

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have few settings in userdefaults  and lots of files in my documents folder. When i give the 2nd version of the app to itunes connect folks what will happen to these 2 contents. I verified it using a small experiment using developer license and it works fine.

Can you get me a authentic iOS developer link which says that these 2 folders will be retained in updation process and also other precautions which has to be taken care for submission of 2nd version of the app to the itunes connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defaults and documents will be kept when updating an app. I've updated my apps many times and never lost either documents or settings.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, the best way to see for yourself that you'll keep everything is to install the old version (on either the simulator or the device), play around with it for a while, and customize some settings... then go ahead and install the new version, effectively simulating the upgrade.The phone looks for differences in the binary itself and the resources, but leaves the user defaults, associated Core Data stores, etc intact.